# Is the video of Greek finance minister Yanis Varoufakis showing a middle finger fake?

Tags: video, greece

On February 12 this year the organizers of the Subversive Festival 2013 in Zagreb, Croatia, [uploaded a video to YouTube](https://youtu.be/MEUWxNifJJ8?t=39m50s) showing a speech of Yanis Varoufakis, who is now the Greek minister of finance. In the video he seems to show his middle finger:

[image: Yanis Varoufakis showing his middle finger]

On Sunday Varoufakis [claimed in a German TV show](https://youtu.be/mZu7DHS3_kM?t=25m44s) that the video *was doctored*, causing a [huge uproar](http://www.spiegel.de/politik/ausland/stinkefinger-varoufakis-beklagt-sich-ueber-jauch-sendung-a-1023742.html) [in the](http://www.faz.net/aktuell/feuilleton/medien/varoufakis-obszoene-geste-den-deutschen-den-stinkefinger-zeigen-13486740.html) [German media](http://www.zeit.de/politik/ausland/2015-03/varoufakis-stinkefinger-jauch-twitter-zagreb). The video was analyzed by journalists all claiming the video is real.

Yesterday evening another German TV show [uploaded a video claiming they indeed faked the finger](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vx-1LQu6mAE) (English subtitles available), including a quite convincing making-of:

[image: Neo Magazin faking video]

Now which is the real version?

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) What sort of evidence would it take to convince you, either way?

Comment: @Oddthinking Honestly I don't know. Statements of the people involved don't carry much weight. The best bet would be maybe an analysis of the two (actually three) different versions (shown in the last video). Maybe some of them contain evidence of editing?

Comment: @georgechalhoub Yes, that is a good point. Let the story develop for a while.

Comment: @Oddthinking - this is 2013. Surely there is a high likelyhood of other people with smartphones recording this, so either supporting or contradictory video is plausible to find. (personally, i don't quite understand what the notability is - what, is it somehow important that a person is capable of showing the finger in terms of their professional qualifications?)

Comment: @DVK At the time of the recording he was largely unknown, so I'm not sure someone else was recording the event. What the notability is? I don't know, but you could hardly open any German newspaper or news site in the last three days without discussion of the gesture. It was even front-paged in the largest German newspaper. I think the main point is that he was calling it faked, not the gesture itself.

Comment: Just for reference: http://kurier.at/kultur/medien/warum-varoufakis-stinkefinger-echt-ist/120.330.396 analyzed both videos shown in the making of and concludes that the one showing the finger is real.

Comment: @Nobody Which goes to show why we do not allow original research as a source on this website: this analysis doesn’t convince me in the least. The only things convincing me either way would be either (a) Böhmermann admitting that the fake was a fake, or (b) somebody official from the festival admitting that they were in cahoots with Böhmermann and uploaded the faked version.

Comment: Isn't Beros somebody official from the festival?

Comment: @Panda Yes but (a) he didn’t deny the prank as far as I know (anything he said was *before* the prank was made public) and (b) even if he did, that’s *much less* convincing than if he admitted the prank. (That said, there are better video analyses than the ones linked here, which show that the finger-less video is faked.)

Comment: Oh, I get the problem now. I had to look at the timeline. Also, I just looked at the other analyses. Thanks!

Comment: It would be better if you post links to the video analyses you mentioned.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: "we do not allow original research as a source" I thought this meant we aren't allowed to do the research in our answers? "... things convincing me ... would be ... Böhmermann/ somebody official admitting ..." that would be unconvincing for me. Böhmermann has no credibility in this anymore and he claimed that some officials of the festival were involved. This discredits most of what is said about this. I would find it much more objective to see a detailed analysis of the videos. The one I linked was the first that I saw. Please post links to better (english) analysis.

Comment: @Nobody I don’t have a video proving the middle finger a fake, though. [I have a video suggesting strongly that the non-finger video is a fake](http://gifmaker.cc/PlayFrameAnimation.php?folder=2015031813TdelK8sV59aAR6Bl7G9PLo), but it’s entirely conceivable that Böhmermann planted that as well, to sow confusion — so it’s far from definitive proof. Video analysis can only get us so far. And a statement from Böhmermann would obviously only convince me if he disavowed his previous claims, i.e. if he admitted that the finger wasn’t fake.

Answer (score 1):

No, the video is real, but it was taken out of context.

The second German TV-Show is [a well known satire show](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZDFneo), and [they freely admit from 8.06 to 8.30 in their video (German with English subtitles)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=Vx-1LQu6mAE#t=486), presumably for legal reasons, that their doctoring is a joke. He follows up criticizing Günther Jauch, the host of the first TV show, for taking Varoufakis' gesture out of context in order to stir anger for populist reasons. Here are is the subtitle transcript from the time range above:

> Dear editorial staff of Günther Jauch, Yanis Varoufakis is wrong, you did not falsify the footage. You simply took it out of context and gave him the runaround, so that the average german could pursue their passion for being angered. "Foreigner. Out of Europe you go! He's poor and takes our money! That's just not possible! We are the bosses in here!" That's what you did. The rest is our effort.

Further, [Varoufakis posted a link to a version of the entire clip he considers authentic](https://twitter.com/yanisvaroufakis/status/577598813050929153). The clip contains some very intelligent analysis of the situation, and provides ample context. However, [the finger is clearly visible](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=MEUWxNifJJ8#t=2428).

While the finger is clearly a colorful element of style, context suggests he is using it to protest how the German government's plan benefits greek and german banks at the expense of greek and german taxpayers, [a claim which is undisputed](http://www.spiegel.de/wirtschaft/eurokrise-hat-die-eu-griechenland-gerettet-oder-banken-a-1018964.html). Der Spiegel writes, in a slightly edited Google translation of the article summary:

> Varoufakis' thesis is that the Troika aid was not an act of solidarity of European citizens and taxpayers with the Greek people, but an act of self-help of the European financial sector at the expense of EU citizens. This thesis can not simply be dismissed out of hand. Reason enough to call the self-righteousness German Wutbürger (anger-driven citizens) into question.

Why Varoufakis attempted to counter Jauch's attack with the doctoring claim, rather than pointing out that he was taken out of context, is unclear. The simplest explanation, in the opinion of the answerer, is that he is inexperienced at dealing with attacks on his character, has no access to expensive political advisors to train him, was taken by surprise, and is now forced to roll with it.

It looks like the host of the satire show is actively helping to seed doubt about the video's authenticity in order to support Varoufakis by using ambigious language and tonality while technically stating the truth. Here is a translation of a [recently uploaded statement](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BRvfZmwwHF0&app=desktop):

> Our video is 100% real. Whoever claims the opposite is a liar. As an apology and gesture of goodwill towards our European friends, Günther Jauch and the Bild newspaper's editorial staff should immediately to leave the Euro zone of their own accord. The accusation that our video were a manipulated fake-fake fake-fake-fake has no merit whatsoever. We would never friviously expose a necessary journalistic debate about a two year old middle finger that was taken out of context to ridicule.

Note that the video detailing fakery is indeed a 100% real piece of satire, just as claimed.

Comment: The section from the video is at best ambiguous about this. As far as I understand it (as a native German speaker) they admit that the Jauch team did not fake the video but that the ZDFNeo team did. It is well in line with a previous action on the TV Total team. Additionally note the highest voted youtube comment on the video linked by Varoufakis himself: 'There is even a signature frame to mark this video as such (a single red frame around 40:10). The same frame also appears in the making-of film by "NEO Magazin Royale".' Which you can verify yourself.

Comment: As someone coming to this late, and with insufficient context or German language skills, I find this somewhat bewildering. I wonder if you could add a timeline of the order that things happened, and the claims being made. (cont'd)

Comment: I think you are saying 1) finger gesture used in 2013, 2) uploaded with red flashes in 2015, 3) used out of context, 4) uproar, 5) confused accusations of doctoring, 6) satirical show doctors two versions to NOT show the finger, claiming them to be the original when they weren't. Is that right?

Comment: @Oddthinking 1-5 are correct, 6 is as follows: Satirical show releases a mockumentary showing its own SFX staff starting with a version without the finger, and working towards a version with the finger. Then they follow up with a statement affirming the authenticity of "their video", leaving unsaid which one they mean.

Comment: @Nobody This is not ambiguous at all "Yanis Varoufakis is wrong, you did not falsify the footage. You simply took it out of context and gave him the runaround"

Comment: @Housemeister: Yes and then "The rest is our effort." which can mean "We faked the footage." which is after all what the making of is about. However, I give you that they might be deliberately vague to mean both here and to cause even more confusion. I think depending on whether you believe the video is fake or not this sentence confirms both views. But as I see it, it is not claiming that the video is not a fake but stating who is the author of this fake. But then again we cannot really trust anything said in the making of because it is satire.

Comment: I am trying to line this up with [this interview](http://www.sueddeutsche.de/politik/wirbel-um-stinkefinger-clip-was-varoufakis-bei-jauch-gesagt-hat-1.2395969), where he denies giving the finger.

Comment: @Housemeister You are right, it’s not ambiguous at all, but *you* are taking it falsely out of context. Böhmermann is *not* saying that the video used by Jauch is undoctored, he’s merely saying that *Jauch* didn’t doctor it. In fact, he’s contradicting you *directly afterwards*. Your whole answer is taking statements out of context to make a point: Varoufakis later disowned his previous statement, and reaffirmed his claim of fakery.

Comment: @georgechalhoub Varoufakis posted a video that *he* considers authentic. It contains the finger. If that won't convince you I don't know what will.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Since I can't quote the entire video I have to select some statements to quote. But no, I provided ample context; it's in a satirical video otherwise detailing fakery.

Comment: @Housemeister I agree that you provided ample context. You simply misunderstand and/or misrepresent fundamentally what is being said: you claim that this states that the video is not faked. This is false, the passage does not state that *at all*.